# Fill doesnt seem to work properly? Or im doing something wrong?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm new to the blender, and I don't understand how "Fill" works. Almost every single time I try to use it, it doesn't fill everything and leave a lot of missing spots.
Example: I have this torus which I'm trying to make a little less round
[image: It's not completely round for the reasons explained later]

I select and then delete the first outer loop of vertices to make it look like this:
[image]

After that, I select last 2 loops and try using "Fill", which does this:
[image]

It's only poorly filling one side, leaving everything else empty, and the only other option that I can think of is slowly and manually make all faces, which I did with the inner side of torus. Am I missing something? Is there's any other way to do that I'm not aware of?
Blender version: 3.3.1

Comment: Ctrl E > Bridge Edge Loops or right click > LoopTools > Bridge (if you've enabled the addon) are the way to do it, in my case if I try to fill it will fill the selected circle, it won't try to bridge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "Bridge Edge Loops" instead, it will work:

[image]